# Selenium Ide: tricks for handling this pop up

Tags: popup, selenium-ide

I'm working with Selenium Ide and I'm in a sticking point because of this pop up.
I need - if it exists - some tricks to pass it. I just need to press OK for going on.
Is there any strategy?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for Selenium IDE to interact with these kind of JavaScript popups unfortunately, your only option really is to change the default behaviour of Firefox when clicking on the link. you can go through it manually and make sure the option to 'do this automatically in the future' is ticked. the other option is to go into 'Options > Applications' and there should be a list of file types in there where you can configure the default behaviour for them.

Answer (score 0):

try Winium.  steps will be

1. your current script to come to this stage

1a. launch Winium driver
1b. perform operation on this dialog with this (winium driver)

2. continue with your script.

do connect with us at defectracker.com to find solution.